# %fieldname is a required field for entry in post media gallery

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, media

I'm pretty new to Magento and I was trying to add a media to a existing product. From code I am able to do that as the following:

```
$entry = ['entry' => [
            'media_type' => ---,
            'position' => ---,
            'types' => [
                ---,
                ---,
                ---,
            ],
            'file' => ---,
            'content' => [
                'base64_encoded_data' => base64_encode(---),
                'type' => ---,
                'name' => ---,
            ]
        ]
        ];
        if (---) {
            $entry['entry']['id'] = ---;
        }

        $saveMedia->whereSku($sku)
            ->withData($entry)
            ->save();
```

The code is working "fine" I am actually trying to use a POST to update an existing image specifing the id but that part it's not working and I get a new image. When I got this error I tried to do the same POST in postman and when I specify in the body the same code as above in json the following error appears:

```
{
    "message": "%fieldName is a required field.",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "entry"
    },
}
```

My json is as following:

```
{"entry":{"media_type":"---","position":---,"types":["image","small_image","thumbnail"],"file":"---","content":{"base64_encoded_data":"---","type":"image\/jpeg","name":"---"},"id":---}}
```

So:

- How do I fix this error? Why isn't my entry recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that inside Postman I tried to add inside the body a "form-data" with the wrong key.. If I paste the same json as above inside "**raw**" body everything works fine!